# Which is the best way to put a try-except-finally in delphi?

Tags: delphi, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi Exception Handling - How to clean up properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473575/delphi-exception-handling-how-to-clean-up-properly)
>   [Use of Try/Finally/Catch Together in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155944/use-of-try-finally-catch-together-in-delphi)

I would like to know which is the best way to put `try-except-finally` in delphi? What I mean is in nested try block, which statement should come inside, for example, Example 1

```
// initialize / allocate resource (create objects etc.)
...
try
     try
        // use resource
        ...
     except
       // handle exception
       ...
     end;
finally
   // free resource / cleanup
   ...
end
```

Example 2

```
    // initialize / allocate resource (create objects etc.)
...
try
     try
        // use resource
        ...
     finally
       // free resource / cleanup           
       ...
     end;
except       
   // handle exception
   ...
end
```

Which is the best way to handle an exception in Delphi, Example 1 or Example 2. why?

Comment: You get your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155944/use-of-try-finally-catch-together-in-delphi.

Comment: I'm coding as in your first example. Creating, using the resource, handle any exception, free the resource. also you can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922995/should-i-put-a-try-finally-block-after-every-object-create